# Why isn't my CSS being applied when the class is added to the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

What I am trying to do is, when i press a button, do put a border around it, to show it as active. I am also trying to have in JavaScript that the button is active, but I haven't gotten to that yet. Can anyone help me?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('button').removeClass('active_button');
  $(this).addClass('active_button');
});

//Home button active on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Home').addClass('active_button');
});
```

```css
.cable-choose {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cable-choose button {
  border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5E6977;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cable-choose button:hover,
.cable-choose button:active,
.cable-choose button:focus {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  outline: none;
}

.active_button {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="cable-config">
  <span>Select Entries</span>

  <div class="cable-choose">
    <button id="Home">50 Entries<br>$5.00</button>
    <button>100 Entries<br>$10.00</button>
    <button>250 Entries<br>$25.00</button>
    <button>500 Entries<br>$50.00</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your CSS selector more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). It was being overridden by the standard button styles.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('button').removeClass('active_button');
  $(this).addClass('active_button');
});

//Home button active on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Home').addClass('active_button');
});
```

```css
.cable-choose {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cable-choose button {
  border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5E6977;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cable-choose button:hover,
.cable-choose button:active,
.cable-choose button:focus {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  outline: none;
}

.cable-choose button.active_button { /* <------------ RIGHT HERE */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="cable-config">
  <span>Select Entries</span>

  <div class="cable-choose">
    <button id="Home">50 Entries<br>$5.00</button>
    <button>100 Entries<br>$10.00</button>
    <button>250 Entries<br>$25.00</button>
    <button>500 Entries<br>$50.00</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's working - I see class="active_button" when I inspect the one I clicked...  Your active_button style is identical to your hover/focus/active state though (one sets to #000 and the other to "black" - same color)

Comment: well it can't be working, becuase when you click on the button, the black border doesn't stick on the button. Try it in the code snippet above

Comment: This isn't an answer. If anything it should have been a comment.

Comment: Oop yep - I looked wrong.  You right.  Aaaand I can't downvote myself?